# Display only last result in fum of series in for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, sum

I'm writing a code to sum a series of numbers but it keep showing all the results. I only need the last result that is the sum of numbers

My Code:

```
//Sum of numbrs which are divisible by either 3 or 5
cout << "\nSum of numbers: ";

for ( numbers = 1; numbers <= limit; numbers++ )
{
    if ( ( numbers%3 == 0 ) || ( numbers%5 == 0 ) )
    {
        if (  !( numbers%3 == 0 && numbers%5 == 0 )  )
        {
            sum += numbers; 
            cout << sum << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sum of numbers: 3 8 14 23 33 45 63 83 104
```

I only need the last value as 104 in the above example.

Comment: You print `sum` inside the `for` loop. You simply need to move `cout << sum << " ";` outside.

Comment: just print the sum after the `for` statment!

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been downvoted. I mean, yes, it seems very clear what the problem is but the downvote seems excessive. Thanks for adding the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `cout << sum << " ";` to be outside the for loop. After all, how can we print the sum before we're even done calculating it?

ie:

```
for ( numbers = 1; numbers <= limit; numbers++ )
{
    ...
}

cout << sum << " ";
```